# How to add support for screen timeout while running a qt5.9 app on linuxfb platform?

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto, systemd, imx6

I'm using a qt5.9 app on imx6slevk board with yocto bsp,

Before running the app I see a virtual terminal on the display and this screen blanks after 10 minutes as specified in the driver file found at Kernel_source > drivers/tty/vt/vt.c

```
 static int blankinterval = 10*60;
```

Just as this file is used for virtual terminal the file qlinuxfbscreen.cpp is used by qt applications running on linuxfb.

I didn't find any option of do_screen_blank or do_screen_unblank in this file

All I found was this function:

```
 static void blankScreen(int fd, bool on)
{
 ioctl(fd, FBIOBLANK, on ? VESA_POWERDOWN : VESA_NO_BLANKING);
}
```

on passing on = 1 the screen goes off completely with no display at all

I tried setting Idleaction in systemd/logind.conf

```
IdleAction=suspend
IdleActionSec=30Sec
```

after this the app turns off after 30 sec but it does so even if I press keys on the matrix keypad, systemd doesn't seem to register key press as active events and the screen turns off.

Is there any patch that I can apply to enable screen timeout? Or could I at least register key press as active event in systemd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to modify your qt app.
The algorithm would be something like

1. Start timer
2. If key pressed reset timer to max value
3. If no key pressed go to suspend mode, you may use:

   `system("echo mem > /sys/power/state")`
4. Wakeup on power key press.